# PHP Simple CSS string parser

Tags: php, css, regex, arrays, parsing

I need to parse some CSS code like:

```
color: black;
font-family:"Courier New";
background:url('test.png');
color: red;
--crap;
```

Into:

```
array (
    'color'=>'red',
    'font-family'=>'"Courier New"',
    'background'=>'url(\'test.png\')',
    '--crap'=>''
)
```

- I need to do this via PHP. I can see this done easily via regexp (well, easy to those that know it, unlike myself :-) ).
- I need the resulting array to be "normalized", there should not be any trailing spaces between tokens, even if they were in the source.
- Valueless css tokens should be included in the array as a key only. (see --crap)
- Quotes (and values in general) should remain as is, except for extra formatting (spaces, tabs); easily removed via trim() or via the relevant regexp switch.
- Please not that at this point, I specifically **do not need a full CSS parser**, ie, there is no need to parse blocks ( `{...}` ) or selectors ( `a.myclass#myid` ).
- Oh, and considering I'll be putting this stuff in an array, it is perfectly ok if the last items ( `color:red;` ) *completely override* the original items ( `color:black;` ).

Comment: Why is there no `:` after `--crap` ?

Comment: Some proprietary CSS is not in key:value format. I'd like to simply support such a format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple version:

```
    $a = array();
    preg_match_all('/^\s*([^:]+)(:\s*(.+))?;\s*$/m', $css, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach ($matches as $match)
            $a[$match[1]] = isset($match[3]) ? $match[3] : null;
```

Sample output:

```
array(4) {
  ["color"]=>
  string(3) "red"
  ["font-family"]=>
  string(13) ""Courier New""
  ["background"]=>
  string(15) "url('test.png')"
  ["--crap"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Not tested with anything except your source data, so I'm sure it has flaws. Might be enough to get you started.

Comment: That sounds just about what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$result = array();
if(preg_match_all('/\s*([-\w]+)\s*:?\s*(.*?)\s*;/m',$input,$m))
        var_dump($m);
        // $m[1] contains all the properties
        // $m[2] contains their respective values.
        for($i=0;$i<count($m[1]);$i++) {
                $result[$m[1][$i]] = $m[2][$i];
        }
}
```

Comment: No such an assumption, sorry ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I found this few weeks back and looks interesting.

http://websvn.atrc.utoronto.ca/wsvn/filedetails.php?repname=atutor&path=/trunk/docs/include/classes/cssparser.php

Example:

```
$Parser = new cssparser();
$Results = $Parser->ParseStr("color: black;font-family:"CourierNew";background:url('test.png');color: red;--crap;");
```

Comment: Considering I need to capture any CSS data, I really don't need this. Also considering it parses selectors (and validates them?!) this is a huge no go.

Comment: Instead of using `ParseStr` you can use `Parse` like `Parse('path/to/style.css')`, the main reason I posted this to show you an alternative to all the regex everyone would be posting, my version tho larger is probably much faster

Answer (score 0):

Why don't take a look at [CSSTidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Again, that code specifically parses the full CSS format; while I just need to parse the format in a CSS block (or style attribute).